# Translating from logical address to physical address. Logical addresses are hex

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, tlb

How do I go about converting hexadecimal addresses to physical addresses to answer this question?  I am thoroughly confused and my teacher is no help due to language barrier.

Suppose a logical address space is 1KB, and the page-size is 16 bytes. Assume no page is in the main memory for this process initially and the pure demand paging is used. Current free frame list is `{2,5,8,1,...}`.  The first frame in the free frame list will be used whenever needed. Suppose TLB has two entries. Both TLB and page table are empty initially. FIFO is used as TLB replacement algorithm. Suppose the following logical address is accessed in order: `0x3d`,`0x30`,`0xe5`,`0x7d`, `0x33`, `0xef`. For each of the following address access:

1. specify the physical address that is mapped to it.
2. Suppose it takes 10 ns to access TLB, and 100ns to access memory, and 8ms to handle page fault. How long time it takes to access this address?

Answer (score 1):

When process starts, cpu needs to access address. So cpu looks for the address inside TLB entries, if it fails to find that entry, then it's a TLB miss, otherwise it's TLB hit. If it's a TLB miss then it look for address in main memory and update TLB with TLB entry for this address. To record where each virtual page of the operating system is placed in physical memory, the operating system keeps a per-process data structure known as a page table.

Main memory is divided into pages of size 16 bytes. Total size of memory = 1KB. So number of pages are 1KB/16 = 2^10/2^4 = 2^6 = 64 pages. To translate logical address into physical address, you have to split it into two components VPN(virtual page number) and offset. As address space is 1KB, you need 10 bits total for virtual address. As page size is 16 bytes you can further divide the virtual address like this, higher 6 bits for VPN and lower 4 bits for offset.

Initially, there is no page in main memory. In order to access 0x3d . It looks up into TLB. As cache is empty initially. It is a TLB miss, go to main memory. Binary form of 0x3d is 0000111101. offset(4bits) = 1101 and VPN = 000011. So offset is 13 byte of page 3. As page table is empty. So its a page fault. Bring physical page into free frame 2 and try to access this memory again and update page table. Now translate the virtual address into physical address. Physical address is 13th byte of page 2(as virtual page 3 maps to physical frame 2) i.e. 0010(frame no) and 1101(offset), 0x2d(in hex). Second time when it tries to access, follow the same procedure and as you can there will be no page fault for 0x30.